# LoggerTest in Scala doesn't recognize log4j2.properties at src/test/resources

Tags: scala, logging, log4j

I'm developing a Logger with a custom log4j.properties for Spark, and it looks like is working properly, but at the moment i run the Scala Tests I'm not able to make my LoggerTest to recognize the log4j2.properties at src/test/resources, but it reads the log4j.properties at /src/main/resources.

In the case I rename the log4j2.properties as log4j.properties, it recognizes the file, but throws the next error:

*ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.*

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Im writing the code in IntelliJ and using Maven.

Thank you in advance

Comment: shouldn't it be `src/test/resources` instead of `test/resources/data` ?

Comment: You are right Thilo, sorry I didn't write it correct, i edited the question. The log4j2.properties for the test is at src/test/resources. I realized in the case I edit the log4j2.properties and I rename it as log4j.properties, it is recognized, but then the console shows me the next error : _ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging._